# How do I highlight Console output in python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a custom file selector, and I would like to be able to highlight particular displayed lines (such as white backdrop and black text on the selected line).

Basically, I want to have the console display a file selector with custom options and I want the currently selected option to be highlighted. I already have the code written for the selector itself.

Edit: I'm planning to run this program on windows command line

Comment: check out the [bullet](https://github.com/Mckinsey666/bullet/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#topic_5) library (that is, if you're planning to use **linux** terminal for output)

Comment: @reportgunner I am running this program on a windows command line, haha. But this library is interesting

Comment: also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal), it works for me on windows when I use Command Prompt via `Cmder` AKA `ConEmu`